# Mo' Money- Making an "algorithm" to solve two variable algebra problems

Tags: python, algebra

> A cash drawer contains 160 bills, all 10s and 50s. The total value of
>   the 10s and 50s is $1,760.
>
> How many of each type of bill are in the drawer? You can figure this
>   out by trial and error (or by doing algebra with pencil and paper),
>   but try to use loops and conditionals to check a plausible
>   possibilities and stop when you find the correct one.

Algebraically, on a piece of paper I figured out that it was four $50 bills and one hundred and fifty six $10 bills. This is because

1. x+y=160
2. 10x+50y=1760

   x=160-y

   10x=1600-10y

   1600-10y+50y=1760

   1600-40y=1760

   40y=1760

   y=4

   x=156

how would I make a model that i could code to solve this or any other version of this problem? I only know the very basic syntax of python as i've never ever programmed before this.

Comment: Are there always two types of bills?

Comment: can u explain how this is suppose to work, that is the flow of the program and what exactly you want to model.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy for the system:

```
x+y=160

10x+50y=1760
```

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 1], [10, 50]])
b = np.array([160, 1760])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
print(x)
```

Outputs:

```
[156.   4.]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a total of two variables, the number of tens and the number of fifties. So you could do nested for-loops. A really blunt way of doing this would be:

```
 for fifties in range(161):
      for tens in range(161-fifties):
            if (fifties+tens == 160) and (50*fifties + 10*tens == 1760):
                 break
```

We can improve that a bit by noting that each time we increase the number of fifties, we decrease the possible number of tens:

```
 for fifties in range(161):
      for tens in range(161-fifties):
            if (fifties+tens == 160) and (50*fifties + 10*tens == 1760:
                 break
```

It can be improved even further by noting that although there are a total of two variables, we have the constraint that they add up to 160. Thus, we can use this constraint to get one given the other:

```
 for fifties in range(161):
      tens = 160 - fifties
      if 50*fifties + 10*tens == 1760:
           break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a dynamic programming approach to this for a general solution:

Set up some edge conditions where there is no answer:

1. If the length of notes it less than 1
2. You have one note but the total is not divisible by the denomination there's no answer.

The take a note off and see if it works by recursively calling the function with the remaining notes and adjusted bill-count/total.

```
def countNotes(notes, total, bills):
    if len(notes) < 1:
        return  
    if len(notes) == 1:
        return [bills] if bills * notes[0] == total else None

    for count in range(bills+1):
        amount = notes[0] * count
        rest = countNotes(notes[1:], total - amount, bills - count)
        if rest:
            return [count, *rest]

countNotes([50, 10], 1760, 160)
#[4, 156]

countNotes([100, 20, 5], 173, 2)
# None -- not possible

countNotes([100, 20, 5, 2], 1255, 61)
#[1, 57, 3, 0]
```

This will return the counts as a list in the same order as the notes passed in. If you're dealing with large lists and totals if could be improved by memoizing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'x': 10, 'y': 50} #create dictionary to hold bill values
total_value = 1760
num_bills = 160

y = (total_value - num_bills *d['x']) / (d['y']-d['x']) #isolating y 

x = num_bills - y # isolating x with y value known

print("the number of ten dollar bills is: " + str(x))
print("the number of fifty dollar bills is: " + str(y))
```